# CSS Vertical and horizontal align a span inside of a div?

Tags: css, alignment

Please look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xMAKq/20/

How could I center the left column text to be centered like this:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use a table for something tabular?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would like to use `text-align: center` and `vertical-align: middle` css properties.

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/eeWFz/)

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `display` and table values (`table-row` and `table-cell`) and then use `vertical-align: middle`, as in http://jsfiddle.net/frozenkoi/xMAKq/22/

Answer (score -1):

add text-align center... see http://jsfiddle.net/jEKsK/1/

Comment: The OP meant *vertical* center. See the image in the question.